# Google Maps autoComplete with material design

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, material-design

I have a question about implementing Google Maps auto complete function in material design:

```
<md-autocomplete flex="" md-no-cache="ctrl.noCache" md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedItem" md-search-text="ctrl.searchText" md-items="item in ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)" md-item-text="item.display" md-floating-label="Favorite state">
    <span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchText">{{item.display}}</span>
</md-autocomplete>
```

[Angular Material autocomplete](https://material.angularjs.org/#/demo/material.components.autocomplete) | [Google Maps autocomplete](http://plnkr.co/edit/hgF0az?p=preview)

How can I use material design's auto complete in google maps auto complete (angular)?

Thanks in advance.

**I've found this solution: i overwrite only the css proprties:**

```
/*maps autocomplete*/
.pac-item{
    font-family:RobotoDraft,Roboto,'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif !important;
    font-weight: 300 !important;
    color: rgb(33,33,33) !important;
    line-height: 40px !important;
    /*font-weight: 800;*/
}

.pac-item-query{
    font-family:RobotoDraft,Roboto,'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif !important;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.pac-item:hover{
    background-color: #eeeeee !important;
    transition: background .15s linear;
}

.pac-container{
    color: rgb(33,33,33) !important;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    /*font-weight: 800;*/
}

.pac-icon, .pac-icon-marker{
    background: none !important;
    background-image: none !important;
}
```

Comment: If you want to integrate them to get checkboxes and/or radio buttons and such elements, here's a good reference: http://plnkr.co/edit/GF3nM3XfYX9El2w11pGo?p=preview

Answer (score 12):

We had the exact same requirement for our app, and we did manage to do it the "proper" way, so here you have the solution with the md-autocomplete directive (using [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org)), taking advantage of the [AutocompleteService API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-queryprediction) from Google.

View:

```
<md-autocomplete md-no-cache="true"
                 md-selected-item="vm.selectedItem"
                 md-search-text-change="vm.search(vm.searchText)"
                 md-search-text="vm.searchText"
                 md-items="item in vm.search(vm.searchText)"
                 md-item-text="item"
                 md-min-length="0"
                 placeholder="Type your address">
  <md-item-template>
    <span md-highlight-text="vm.searchText" md-highlight-flags="^i">{{item}}</span>
  </md-item-template>
  <md-not-found>
    No matches found for "{{vm.searchText}}".
  </md-not-found>
</md-autocomplete>
```

Controller:

```
vm.search = search;

function search(address) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  getResults(address).then(
    function (predictions) {
      var results = [];
      for (var i = 0, prediction; prediction = predictions[i]; i++) {
        results.push(prediction.description);
      }
      deferred.resolve(results);
    }
  );
 return deferred.promise;
}   

function getResults(address) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  vm.gmapsService.getQueryPredictions({input: address}, function (data) {
    deferred.resolve(data);
  });
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Just remember to create the service on your controller activation:

```
vm.gmapsService = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
```

And to add the javascript dependency on your main app file:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KE‌​Y&libraries=places"></script>
```

All the vm. stuff is because we use the [John Papa Styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide)

Hope it works for you!

Comment: vm.search =  search; That one line is missing in your posting. Will take a newbie a whole lot of time to figure that one out.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.

Comment: If anyone is struggling to get this working and didn't know about the vm - you must specify your controller as vm...

e.g autoCompleteController as vm

Comment: great contribution! Just please notes that now google places requires also an API key `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>`

Comment: @LeoLozes What does it mean to create the service on your controller activation in Angular 4? I'm not familiar with AngularJS terminology. What is controller?
 Can You help?

Comment: @MarcinKapusta I'm sorry, I switched to React after Angular. I think that Controllers are not very common anymore. Basically, make sure you create the AutocompleteService before you use it, typically in your component creation lifecycle. Anyway, this answer is for Angular Material, I guess that if you're using Angular 4 you should be using Angular Material 2 (https://github.com/angular/material2) and it must have changed significally ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes I think you are onto something. The google auto-completion has it's own DOMrendered on the top (or bottom? sorry I cant remenber) of the document and event handlers binding to them.

The easy way out is overwrite the css rules to meet your requirements. But if that doesn't workout, you can always use google geocode API

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/ to work with Material design md-autocomplete directive. You get flexibility to work with just json format geo data from restful API and do whatever you want with it., But the trade off is you lose some capability (e.g. you cannot sort the match based on your current place, you have to use region or city to manually restrict them).